# Leaflet renders big lines

Tags: leaflet, rendering

On opening the page i get this type of view.The lines are very thick. On clicking anywhere in the map it changes to 2nd picture.I am not being able to figure out why this is happening.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using any plugins, which could collide with the rendering engine of the library?

Comment: I am using some plugins, how can i find out which one is messing?

Comment: Browsing the source code is the best solution, however basic guessing can help narrowing down the options. For example, plugins listed in [markers and renderers](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#markers--renderers) are potential ones.

Comment: remove and add layer and refreshing the layer gives same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaflet has some problem in rendering huge files at start. 
Solution:

- Delay loading of large files
- Make file size small if possible
- If both fails, force leaflet to redraw the layer after loading. (adding a random popup will force redraw)